# Is this exercise from Tao's Analysis 1 erroneous?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, natural-numbers

On page 68 of the fourth edition of Tao's Analysis 1, is *Exercise $3.5.12$*, the first part of which I believe is erroneous. The exercise is stated as follows:

(*Note: $n++$ refers to the successor of $n$*)

> Let $X$ be a set, let $f:\mathbf{N}\times X\to X$ be a function, and let $c$ be an element of $X$. Show that there exists a function $a:X\to X$ such that
> $$a(0) = c$$
> and
> $$a(n++) = f(n,a(n)) \text{ for all }n\in\mathbf{N},$$
> and furthermore that this function is unique.

The required properties of the function $a$ imply that the natural numbers lie in its domain. However, the domain specified here is any arbitrary set $X$ which may not contain the natural numbers. If the domain of $a$ was restricted to the set of natural numbers, the statement of the exercise itself serves as a complete definition of the function, from which it's existence and uniqueness follow directly (I may be wrong here. Do correct me if that's the case). However, this exercise is followed by a fairly elaborate hint, which indicates that the solution may not be this trivial.

Alternatively, if $X$ was defined to be some set that contains the natural numbers but isn't limited to them, one could define $a$ as in the exercise statement for the natural numbers and as some constant for all elements of $X$ that aren't natural numbers, but then there would be no guarantee of uniqueness, as there would be more than one choice of this constant.

Thus, it seems to me that this exercise is somewhat incorrect, but I would like to get some more opinions on this. Any views you may have on this would be much appreciated.

*Update: This error has now been reported, acknowledged, and listed as an erratum on the book's official site [which can be found here.](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/)*

Comment: Yeah, I think the domain of $a$ should be $N$. This is the standard definition of a function by primitive recursion.

Comment: It seems to me that the only thing that is wrong, is the domain of $a$. Namely, it should be $a: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ and we are ready to go. The idea of the exercise is to prove that we can define functions recursively.

Comment: And $n++$ should be $n+1$.

Comment: Also, it is not trivial that $$ a(n++) = f(n, a(n))  $$ gives you existence and uniqueness. That is because you would need to know that $a$ exists (and is unique) before you can make sense of $f(n,a(n))$, which is what you want to show at this stage. You need to use that we are on the natural numbers.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. It makes much more sense now. Also, @TedShifrin, while it is true that $n++ = n+1$, is used the notation I did because that is what appears in the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that it is probably a typo. The following is the exercise on page $68$ of Analysis $1$, third edition. The set $X$ is the set of natural numbers $N$.
[image]

Comment: One does not need that $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Of course, we could reduce to this case as the relevant part of $X$ is $a(\mathbb{N})$ which is countable, but that is not really the point :)